# How to Prevent Checksum() from generating Duplicate Values in sql server

Tags: t-sql

As it is known there is a probable chance of `checksum` generating duplicate values, and I am supposed to find an approach which prevents `checksum` from generating duplicate Values...
Please help

Thanks n Regards

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't need to. If you want a unique identification, a finite-size value (a checksum) isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. CHECKSUM can never be guaranteed unique.

[MSDN for CHECKSUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) says to use [HASHBYTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) instead which has far less chance of duplications.

However, any hashing function **can not** guarantee 100% that you will have no duplicates. if you want "no duplicates" then you shouldn't hash...

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [HashBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx)

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx):

> When an MD5 hash algorithm is
>   specified, the probability of HashBytes returning the same result for
>   two different inputs is much lower than that of CHECKSUM.

Example:

```sql
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(4000);
SELECT @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),'dslfdkjLK85kldhnv$n000#knf');
SELECT HashBytes('SHA1', @HashThis);
GO
```