# Pseudo-anonymize User IDs within locations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, window-functions

Suppose I have the following table

```
|   City |   Name |
|--------|--------|
|  Paris |    Tim |
|  Paris |  Alice |
|  Paris | Sandra |
|  Paris | Sandra |
|  Paris |   Lisa |
| London |    Joe |
| London |    Joe |
| London |    Tim |
| London |  Peter |
```

And I want generate an (pseudo) "anonymized" name per city for each unique user (for instance `city`  name per city suffixed by `_n` where n is a simple count for each unique name per city).

I could do the following

```sql
SELECT City
       , Name
       , CONCAT(City, '_', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY Name)) AS anon_name
  FROM employees
 GROUP BY City
          , Name;
```

which gives me what I want:

```
|   City |   Name | anon_name |
|--------|--------|-----------|
| London |    Joe |  London_1 |
| London |  Peter |  London_2 |
| London |    Tim |  London_3 |
|  Paris |  Alice |   Paris_1 |
|  Paris |   Lisa |   Paris_2 |
|  Paris | Sandra |   Paris_3 |
|  Paris |    Tim |   Paris_4 |
```

However, I am not very happy with the solution as the users can be derived as the number is simply assigned alphabetically.

Instead of a sequence I could use `NEWID()`:

```sql
SELECT City
       , Name
       , CONCAT(City, '_', NEWID()) AS anon_name
  FROM employees
 GROUP BY City
          , Name;
```

```
|   City |   Name |                                   anon_name |
|--------|--------|---------------------------------------------|
| London |    Joe | London_A06BFFC9-E122-4CB2-AFDE-B1980EC50A1F |
| London |  Peter | London_B153D072-F75A-4004-B922-189D64656AC1 |
| London |    Tim | London_AF40F949-5D55-4896-907F-17EE0165C569 |
|  Paris |  Alice |  Paris_9F779CFA-B799-409A-801B-9CC044295B13 |
|  Paris |   Lisa |  Paris_CFA8AB45-CCEF-4223-B86B-8A71A8335D13 |
|  Paris | Sandra |  Paris_1FEE5266-8FFF-431E-A76D-CB490FE77BB4 |
|  Paris |    Tim |  Paris_A7BAF19F-1B97-470D-BF41-81C5B6BFFCBA |
```

This generates quite long labels, but it is not possible to relate it to the name.

Hence, my question:

Can I get the short version (that is just a number suffix) which is however randomized such that the name cannot be easily derived from the number, such as in

```
|   City |   Name | anon_name |
|--------|--------|-----------|
| London |    Joe |  London_2 |
| London |  Peter |  London_1 |
| London |    Tim |  London_3 |
|  Paris |  Alice |   Paris_1 |
|  Paris |   Lisa |   Paris_2 |
|  Paris | Sandra |   Paris_4 |
|  Paris |    Tim |   Paris_3 |
```

---

Sample Data generated by:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees
    ([City] varchar(8), [Name] varchar(8))
;
    
INSERT INTO employees
    ([City], [Name])
VALUES
    ('Paris', 'Tim'),
    ('Paris', 'Alice'),
    ('Paris', 'Sandra'),
    ('Paris', 'Sandra'),
    ('London', 'Joe'),
    ('London', 'Joe'),
    ('London', 'Tim'),
    ('London', 'Peter')
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `newid()` in the first expression:

```
SELECT City, Name,
       CONCAT(City, '_', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY NEWID())) AS anon_name
FROM employees
GROUP BY City, Name;
```

If you just want a randomized suffix, you could use `checksum()`:

```
SELECT City, Name,
       CONCAT(City, '_', CHECKSUM(Name)) AS anon_name
FROM employees
GROUP BY City, Name;
```

However, there is the risk of collision -- where two users with the same name have different checksums.  There are ways around this, if you don't want sequential ids.

Comment: Ah so close, interesting approach with `CHECKSUM`, but not sure I understood your caveat. I must be able so see from my data that the same user gets the same randomized id, does the `CHECKSUM` approach guarantee that with all likelihood?

Comment: @thothal . . . The `group by` guarantees that per city, regardless of the method used. 
 "Tim" has a different suffix in the two cities.  The `checksum()` as shown here would give the same suffix for the two cities, but that is easily adjusted by using `checksum(city + name)` so they are different.

Comment: @thothal Suggested reading: [How to Prevent Checksum() from generating Duplicate Values in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856562/how-to-prevent-checksum-from-generating-duplicate-values-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 1):

How about a randomly sorted `row_number()`?

```
SELECT 
    City,
    Name,
    CONCAT(City, '_', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY newid())) AS anon_name
 FROM employees
 GROUP BY City, Name;
```